# Can I remove script tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Can `<script>` tags and all of their contents be removed from HTML with BeautifulSoup, or do I have to use Regular Expressions or something else?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<script>a</script>baba<script>b</script>', 'html.parser')
for s in soup.select('script'):
    s.extract()
print(soup)
baba
```

Comment: What's the best way to chain on additional tags to be removed? Right now it works if I repeat the command one after another, with [s.extract() for s in soup('script')] then [s.extract() for s in soup('iframe')] and so on, but not if I chain them like so [s.extract() for s in soup('iframe', 'script')].

Comment: @Ali You would have to use `[s.extract() for s in soup(['iframe', 'script'])]` Note that to use multiple tags, the parameter must be a list

Comment: @FábioDiniz How would I extract something like: `'<script class="blah">a</script>baba<script id="blahhhh">b</script>'`? Is it the same?

Comment: To get the final string with the elements removed in code, call str(soup)

Comment: The soup object becomes useless after this operation, no tags are found anymore.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance can you please explain what putting the code in a list does?

Comment: @FábioDiniz What if I wanted to do the opposite? remove ALL tags except for the <img> tag? Thanks

Comment: This is outdated, BeautifulSoup seems to format the string to html now :
`<html><head></head><body><p>baba</p></body></html>`

Comment: I was trying to add the element tag(Original variable) to a new variable and then apply the remove operation on the new variable and it even affects the original variable as well, how can this be fixed? what is the approach to do the same?

Comment: @FábioDiniz is there way to remove a tag with a specific class? I don't want to remove all tags with same name, but just one tag with a specific class

Answer (score 50):

Updated answer for those who might need for future reference:
The correct answer is.
[`decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose).
You can use different ways but `decompose` works in place.

Example usage:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>This is a slimy text and <i> I am slimer</i></p>')
soup.i.decompose()
print str(soup)
#prints '<p>This is a slimy text and</p>'
```

Pretty useful to get rid of detritus like `<script>`, `<img>` and so forth.

Comment: The difference between `decompose` and `extract` is that the latter returns the thing that was removed, whereas the former just destroys it.  So this is the more precise answer to the question, but the other methods do work.

Comment: Decompose does not remove the content of script tags, it only removes the tags.

Comment: I agree with both your comments. Which is why I said correct answer as per OP which was to `remove` contents. Often used for cleaning HTML of unneeded tags and formatting.

Comment: Actually, according to the documentation: "Tag.decompose() removes a tag from the tree, then completely destroys it and its contents:" https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose

Comment: It works but will fail if there is no `<i>` in the HTML. When you are not sure about the HTML structure then `extract` is better

Comment: If you are not sure about the HTML you can't use `strict` mode and yes then falling back to extract might be the only way.

Comment: @Vangel Apologies, I think I forgot to add a mention in my comment: I believe I was responding to Roland Pihlakas with that comment.

Comment: Taking into account that we may have several `i` tags and want to remove all of them, we can (analogously to @FábioDiniz `extract` example above) do `[s.decompose() for s in soup('i')]`. `decompose()` by itself only removes the first occurrence.

Comment: @Orange Iam also trying to do the same, do you have a solution for that? ( to remove multiple occurrences of the tag)

Comment: @SundeepPidugu To remove tag with multiple occurrence you can use - 
[soup.i.decompose() for tag in soup.find_all('i')]

Comment: As pointed out `decompose()` has no explicit return value so wrapping it in a list comprehension—while technically allowed—is generally [not advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597). However if one is restricted to a one-liner while writing a comment, it's unclear to me what the proper form could actually look like. Using `for s in soup('i'): s.decompose()` would not generate a list of `None` values, however when not assuming an implicit expansion of the compound statement it would be a [`E701`](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html) style issue.

Answer (score 31):

As stated in the ([official documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html)) you can use the `extract` method to remove all the subtree that matches the search.

```
import BeautifulSoup
a = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup("<html><body><script>aaa</script></body></html>")
[x.extract() for x in a.findAll('script')]
```

Comment: Is there way to remove a tag with a specific class? I don't want to remove all tags with same name, but just one tag block with a specific class.

Comment: All you have to do is to select specific elements to call `extract` to.
`[x.extract() for x in a.select('span.className')]`