# Not able to parse HTML with mechanize or requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-2.6, mechanize-python

i'm trying to get/view an HTML code for a certain website however i'm not able to do so, below is a snip of my code and the output that i got

```
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


page = browser.open('https://www.My-Website.com')
source_code = page.read()
print source_code

try:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
    images = soup.findAll('img')
```

output

```
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="CacheControl" content="no-cache"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function decode_string(in_str) { return decodeURIComponent(in_str); }
    function test(){var table = "00000000 77073096 EE0E612C 990951BA 076DC419 706AF48F    
    ... 

    var c = 1354021302
    var slt = "iM78ylW5"
    ...
   for (var i=0; i<n; i++)
   arr[i] = s1;
   for (var i=0; i<m-1; i++){
   for(var j=n-1; j>=0;--j) {
   var t = arr[j].charCodeAt(0);
   t++; arr[j] = String.fromCharCode(t);
    if (arr[j].charCodeAt(0)<=end) {
    break;} else { arr[j] = s1 ;}}
    var chlg = arr.join(""); var str = chlg + slt;
    var crc = 0;
    var crc = crc ^ (-1);
    for( var k = 0, iTop = str.length; k < iTop; k++ ){ crc = (crc >> 8) ^ ("0x"            table.substr(((crc ^ str.charCodeAt(k) ) & 0x000000FF) * 9, 8));}

    document.cookie = "TSd58639_75=" + "a26b965e6341773f64088b486e1859bf:" + chlg + ":" +     slt + ":" + crc + ";Max-Age=3600;path=/";
document.forms[0].elements[2].value=decode_string(document.forms[0].elements[2].value)
document.forms[0].elements[4].value=decode_string(document.forms[0].elements[4].value)
if (document.forms[0].attributes['action']!=undefined) { document.forms[0].attributes['action'].value = decode_string(document.forms[0].attributes['action'].value) ;} else {document.forms[0].action = decode_string(document.forms[0].action);}
document.forms[0].submit();}
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="test()">
  <form method="POST" action="%2f">
  </form>
  <input type="hidden" name="TSd58639_id" value="3" />
  <input type="hidden" name="TSd58639_md" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="TSd58639_rf" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="TSd58639_ct" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="TSd58639_pd" value="0" />
 </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE
i used tidylib to my script as the following

```
document, errors = tidy_document(source_code)
print document
print errors
```

the output of the error is:-

```
line 1 column 1 - Warning: missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration
line 35 column 159 - Warning: <input> isn't allowed in <body> elements
line 35 column 45 - Info: <body> previously mentioned
line 35 column 159 - Warning: inserting implicit <form>
line 1 column 7 - Warning: inserting missing 'title' element
line 35 column 159 - Warning: <form> lacks "action" attribute
```

NOTES

-when i use FF or other browsers to view the page source code i noticed this msg

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

-i tried with latest beautifulsoup4 4.3.1 but got same result

-i get same result with requests library as well.

-it looks similar to this post
[Python unable to retrieve form with urllib or mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352674/python-unable-to-retrieve-form-with-urllib-or-mechanize)  but didn't work with me

Please help

Comment: Can you provide page source?

Comment: it's pretty big, it contains many java script could this affect ?     any idea ?

Comment: Let's start with request headers. Or at least headers['content-type']

Comment: print r.headers['content-type'] > text/html    
print r.encoding  > ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it was a java problem, same code worked with python selenium. thanks