# Using mechanize to input username and password

Tags: python, screen-scraping, mechanize

How do I use mechanize to input username and password onto this site?

**I deleted and changed my post because my previous one had too much extra information**

I've read in other posts that maybe this has to do with javascript, but how do I tell? and what do I do with that information?

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

url = 'https://www.pin1.harvard.edu/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pin1.harvard.edu%2Fpin%2Fauthenticate%3F__authen_application%3DFAS_AC_AUTHENTICATOR'
#req = requests.get(url)
#dom = web.Element(req.text)

#Handles all the browser details 
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
#self.browser = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())

#Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.open(url)


#Select First Form
#br.select_form(nr=1)

#br['username'] = '40839852'

#print list(br.forms())[0] 

for form in br.forms():
    print "Form name:", form.name
    print form
    break

br.select_form(name= formname)
br[searchname] = term
res = br.submit()
content = res.read()
dom = web.Element(content)
```

TRACEBACK

```
ParseError: unexpected '/' char in declaration
---> 32 for form in br.forms():
     33     print "Form name:", form.name
     34     print form
```

UPDATE - BASED ON PACO'S SUGGESTION I ADDED...But i still get a traceback. 
[Python unable to retrieve form with urllib or mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352674/python-unable-to-retrieve-form-with-urllib-or-mechanize)

```
beg =  re.search(t, res.read()).span()[1]
res.set_data(res.get_data()[beg:])
br.set_response(response)
br.select_form(nr=0)


<ipython-input-25-bd1b73406b45> in <module>()
     28 br.set_response(response)
     29 
---> 30 br.select_form(nr=0)
     31 
     32 
ParseError: unexpected '-' char in declaration
```

Comment: long shot, but I'm guessing that `br.forms` isn't a function. What happens if you remove the parentheses?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a function i think. http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/ if you remove the parens, you get: <bound method Browser.forms of <mechanize._mechanize.Browser instance at 0x1095e7d40>>

Comment: might be easier to do this in selenium

Comment: can you give me a code snippet using selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I selected the first form in my code.

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
#Form fields to populate
br.form['username'] = username
br.form['password'] = password
#Submit the login form
br.submit()
```

Modify it to suit your needs. The "nr=0" is probably what you're looking for.

But the problem is the DOCTYPE. I tested the following, and it strips it out.

```
html = br.response().get_data().replace('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd >', '')
response = mechanize.make_response(
    html, [("Content-Type", "text/html")],
url, 200, "OK")
br.set_response(response)
```

I took this straight from the [Mechanize FAQ.](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html)

Comment: unfortunately I still get the parseerror traceback saying unexpected '/' char in declaration. It's something to do with the select_form function

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParseError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7eb5e7e1b1f8> in <module>()
     23 
     24 
---> 25 br.select_form(nr=0)

Comment: What do I do if I do find that there are errors? (1) Mismatch between Public and System identifiers in the DOCTYPE declaration (2)  No Character encoding declared at document level

Comment: by strip out, you mean to just delete it?

Comment: how did you know that '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC...' was the thing to replace?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ will explain why when you put that URL into their validator -  "Mismatch between Public and System identifiers in the DOCTYPE declaration", which can lead to a parsing error. Web browsers are more forgiving than Mechanize and other parsers.