# Removing all HTML tags along with their content from text

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am wondering how I can delete all HTML tags along with their contents using `BeautifulSoup`.

Input:

```
... text <strong>ha</strong> ... text
```

Output:

```
... text ... text
```

Comment: But if you remove all the HTML tags from an HTML document, you're just going to end up with an empty string. Do you only want to remove _certain_ tags? Or all tags within some top-level tag?

Comment: A more pythoning answer may be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598524/can-i-remove-script-tags-with-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`replace_with()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) (or `replaceWith()`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag


text = "text <strong>ha</strong> ... text"

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

for tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
    tag.replaceWith('')

print soup.get_text()
```

prints:

```
text  ... text
```

Or, as @mata suggested, you can use `tag.decompose()` instead of `tag.replaceWith('')` - will produce the same result, but looks more appropriate.

Comment: [`decompose`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) would probably be the more appropriate choice.

Comment: @mata: You should probably write that as a separate answer.

Comment: @alecxe The tag may not be necessarily <strong>

Comment: Also I don't get it, how will I grab the result? tag.replaceWith('') is not assigning anything.

Comment: @AdamSilver it works in place of a `soup` object. Use `get_text()` to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

This is for XML, if you want it for HTML, change the import from `BeautifulStoneSoup` to `BeautifulSoup`

```
try:
    #Using bs4
    from bs4 import BeautifulStoneSoup
    from bs4 import Tag
except ImportError:
    #Using bs3
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
    from BeautifulSoup import Tag

def info_extract(isoup):
    '''
    Recursively walk a nested list and upon finding a non iterable, return its string
    '''
    tlist = []
    def info_extract_helper(inlist, count = 0):
        if(isinstance(inlist, list)):
            for q in inlist:
                if(isinstance(q, Tag)):
                    info_extract_helper(q.contents, count + 1)
                else:
                    extracted_str = q.strip()
                    if(extracted_str and (count > 1)):
                        tlist.append(extracted_str)
    info_extract_helper([isoup])
    return tlist

xml_str = \
'''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <first-tag>
      <second-tag>
        <events-data>
           <event-date someattrib="test">
                <date>20040913</date>
           </event-date>
        </events-data>

      <events-data>
         <event-date>
           <date>20040913</date>
         </event-date>
      </events-data> 
     </second-tag>
   </first-tag>
'''

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_str)
print info_extract(soup)
```