# How do I remove tags in between other html tags using beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Building off this post: [Can I remove script tags with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598524/can-i-remove-script-tags-with-beautifulsoup)

Say I have an html doc as such:

```
'<td><script class="blah">a</script>baba<script id="blahhhh">b</script></td>'
```

How would I remove the script tags, but leave the text between the script tags, so the output would be:

```
'<td>ababab</td>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

VALID_TAGS = ['td']

def sanitize_html(value):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(value)

    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name not in VALID_TAGS:
            tag.hidden = True

    return soup.renderContents()
```

This retains the content of the invalid tags.

[Python HTML sanitizer / scrubber / filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699468/python-html-sanitizer-scrubber-filter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `getText()` to get content of a tag without child tags :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<td><script class="blah">a</script>baba<script id="blahhhh">b</script></td>')
td = soup.td
#update content of <td> to concatenation of all inner text nodes
td.string = td.getText()
print(soup)
```

Output :

```
<html><body><td>ababab</td></body></html>
```