# Remove multiline HTML in Python

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to strip out particular chunks of HTML documents, particularly Javascript (`<script></script>`) and inline CSS (`<style></style>`). Currently I'm trying to use `re.sub()` but am not having any luck with Multiline. Any tips?

```
import re

s = '''<html>
<head>
  <title>Some Template</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{path to Library}/base.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="something.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="simple.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // HelloWorld template
    document.write(examples.simple.helloWorld());
  </script>
</body>
</html>'''

print(re.sub('<script.*script>', '', s, count=0, flags=re.M))
```

Comment: Why are you not going for [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro My understanding of BeautifulSoup isn't extensive, but all my uses have been for parsing HTML and extracting content. I only want to clean out parts of it, and convert other parts like Bold and Italic tags to a different markup. I'm not aware of BS4 being capable of that.

Comment: Well, you can clean out parts of the HTML. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5598678/2932244).

Comment: You can even modify the HTML tree by changing its tag name and/or attributes. Have a look at the [doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-the-tree).

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro Huh... I'll be. Throw that up in an answer and the credit's yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, since you are parsing and modifying HTML, I'd suggest to use a HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

If you simply want to strip/remove all the `script` tags within the HTML tree. You can use [`.decompose()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) or [`.extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract).

`.extract()`  will *return the tag* that was extracted whereas `.decompose()` will simply *destroy* it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
for i in soup('script'):
    i.decompose()

print(soup)
```

As discussed in the comments, you can do additional modifications to the HTML tree. You may refer the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-the-tree) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need DOTALL modifier not Multiline .

```
print(re.sub(r'(?s)<script\b.*?</script>', '', s))
```

This would remove the leading spaces exists before `script` tag.

```
print(re.sub(r'(?s)\s*<script\b.*?</script>', '', s))
```