# python remove specific lines from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file-io

i want to delete specific lines in this Html file. I want to look where the String STARTDELETE is and remove from there +1 to the String ENDDELETE -1

i have marked the lines to delete with 'xxx' for better understanding. How can i do it with python?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Image Gallery</h2>
    <div class="row"> <!--STARTDELETE-->
      xxx<div class="col-xs-3">
        xxx<div class="thumbnail">
          xxx<a href="/w3images/lights.jpg" target="_blank">
          xxx<img  style="padding: 20px" src="xxx" alt="bla" >
          xxx<div class="caption">
            xxx<p>Test</p>
          xxx</div>
        xxx</a>
        xxx</div>
      xxx</div>
    </div> <!--ENDDELETE-->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may be able to use a library like [beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598524/can-i-remove-script-tags-with-beautifulsoup) or even an xml parser to do it. If you want any more specific suggestions you might want to show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [beautifulsoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (an HTML parser/DOM manipulator)

Read the data, get a "DOM" (kind of... a walkable structure) with beautifulsoup, fetch the item that you wanna empty, and [remove its children](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose).

In your example it looks like you want to empty `<div>(s)` whose `class=row`, right? Let's assume your HTML data is stored in a file called `data.html` (this will probably not be like that in your particular case... it'll be a request's body or something like that)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('data.html', 'r') as page_f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_f.read(), "html.parser")
    # In `soup` we have our "DOM tree"

divs_to_empty = soup.find("div", {'class': 'row'})
for child in divs_to_empty.findChildren():
    child.decompose()

print(soup.prettify())
```

This outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>
   Bootstrap Example
  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <h2>
    Image Gallery
   </h2>
   <div class="row">
    <!--STARTDELETE-->
   </div>
   <!--ENDDELETE-->
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you're gonna be doing DOM manipulation I strongly suggest you read and play with beautiful soup (it is quite powerful)

Comment: the data.html must be in the same folder?

Comment: i get the error:     for child in divs_to_empty.findChildren():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findChildren'

But maybe i did something wrong with the path

Comment: `data.html` is just a "fixture" I used to get a valid example working. Chances are you won't have it stored in a file (it will be part of a request's body or something like that)

Comment: how ever now it works :) dont know what i did wrong. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can first copy and paste that code into an input file, maybe named "input.txt", then output the lines you want to keep to "output.txt". Ignore the lines you want to delete.

```
w = open("output.txt", "w")  # your output goes here
delete = False
with open("input.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if "<!--ENDDELETE-->" in line:
            delete = False # stops the deleting
        if not delete:
            w.write(str(line))
        if "<!--STARTDELETE-->" in line:
            delete = True # starts the deleting
w.close() # close the output file
```

Hope this helps!