# How to remove span tags inside span tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to remove span tags within span tags, but have not found a solution yet.
script I've tried as below:

```
request = 'http://urltargethere/adeas/asd'
r = urlopen(request).read()
sew = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
results = sew.findAll("span", {"class": "titles"})
for x in results:
    print 'text ==> ', x
```

**the result of print is:**

```
<span class="titles"><span class="times">1 hour ago</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
<span class="titles"><span class="times">2 hour ago</span>Tara enim ad minim veniam.</span>
<span class="titles"><span class="times">3 hour ago</span>Morol eiusmodtempor incididunt.</span>
```

the result I'm looking for is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Tara enim ad minim veniam.
Morol eiusmodtempor incididunt.
```

Comment: print 'text ==> ', x.text  or print 'text ==> ', x.text.strip()

Comment: if using "x.text", text in the "times" class is still picked up, I want to delete "span.times" and its contents

Comment: replace {"class": "titles"} with {"class": "times"}

Comment: to remove a tag try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598678/7887883

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the final text of the span title class, '.contents' will return a list of the elements of the span (the times span and the text), so you can index the one you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
<span class="title"><span class="times">1 hour ago</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
<span class="title"><span class="times">2 hour ago</span>Tara enim ad minim veniam.</span>
<span class="title"><span class="times">3 hour ago</span>Morol eiusmodtempor incididunt.</span>''','html.parser')

for s in soup.findAll('span',{'class':'title'}):
    print(s.contents[1])
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Tara enim ad minim veniam.
Morol eiusmodtempor incididunt.
```

Comment: This is one of those cases where it'd be great if `soup.select('span.title::text')` worked or one could directly do: `soup.xpath('//span[@class="title"]/text()')` or similar...

Answer (score 1):

Try this to shake off the portion you don't wish to keep:

```
content="""
<span class="title"><span class="times">1 hour ago</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
<span class="title"><span class="times">2 hour ago</span>Tara enim ad minim veniam.</span>
<span class="title"><span class="times">3 hour ago</span>Morol eiusmodtempor incididunt.</span>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for item in soup.find_all(class_="title"):
    [tag.extract() for tag in item.find_all(class_="times")]
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Tara enim ad minim veniam.
Morol eiusmodtempor incididunt.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a = '<span class="times">1 hour ago</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'

soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all("span", {'class':'times'}):
    tag.replaceWith('')

print soup.get_text()
```

Result:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```