# Trying to filter results using BeautifulSoup but results stay the same?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to filter results using BeautifulSoup, and although I change what I'm filtering by, I keep being given the same output, including a couple hundred lines that look like this:

```html
var EVENT_ADD_PKG="evtAddPkg";
var EVENT_DELETE_PKG="evtDelPkg";
var EVENT_VIEW_PKG="evtViewPkg";
var EVENT_EDIT_PKG="evtEditPkg";

var EVENT_CHANGE_COMP_FREQ = "changeCompFreq";
var EVENT_CHANGE_COMP_FREQ_VALID_DONE = "changeCompFreqVaidationDone";
var EVENT_CHANGE_COL_DATE = "eventChangeColDate";
var EVENT_CHANGE_START_DATE = "eventStartDate";
var EVENT_DELETE_ALL_PKGS = "deleteAllPkgs";
```

This page does have a number of input fields that I assume these lines are for, and I do need the input from some of them, but I think its a better idea to filter them out first.

I've navigated to the right ajax webpage using Selenium and am being given the right text I want at the bottom of all these lines, but obviously I can't use this output for anything with all these extra lines.

How do I filter these out?

This is the code I'm using right now to scrape the page:

```py
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for tag in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(tag.text)
```

Comment: Looks like JS to me. If you like to filter out everything inside <script> tags, you might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598524/can-i-remove-script-tags-with-beautifulsoup).

Comment: Thank you, that link set me on the right path to filter out those results!